# Show and hide Bootstrap Navbar's buttons based on screen width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using pretty Common setup of twitter Bootstrap 3 navbar-header.

**SETUP:**

1. `navbar-header` has 2 `navbars`
2. one `navbar` is floating left with lots of buttons (extending height of `navbar-header`)
3. 2nd `navbar` is floating right

**REQUIREMENT:**

1. I want to have fixed height of navbar-header and since i am using lots of buttons on floating left menu , navbar-header expands in height
2. I want to hide extra buttons on floating left `navbar` that will cause `navbar-header` to expand in height
3. this should work on `$(window).resize(function() {});`

In simple words, when window is resized , extra buttons should hide and shown based on available size so that `navbar-header` does not expand in height.

***Currently I am having trouble with floating right menu.***

**JSFIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/wsxa0zae/4/
Try resizing window

```
var adjustable = function() {
var collection = [];
  $('.adjustable-drop').find('> li').removeClass('hide').each(function() {
    if (this.offsetTop > 51) {
      collection.push(this);
    } 
  });
  $(collection).addClass('hide');
};


$(window).resize(function() {
  adjustable(); 
});
$(window).trigger('resize');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPD**. I've improved my solution. (The first version is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/yt985oxf/1/).)

1. I've used [`.outerWidth()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerwidth/) and [`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) methods instead of the `.offsetTop`.
2. I guess you can remove `<div class="container-fluid"></div>` from the Navbar because the Navbar is wrapped into `<div class="container"></div>`.
3. We need to show all elements of the Navbar when the width of the screen is 767px or less.

Please check the result: https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/yt985oxf/

```js
var selectNavbar = $('#navbar');
var selectNavbarHeader = $('.navbar-header');

var adjustable = function() {
  if ( document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 767 ) {
    $('.adjustable-drop .hide').removeClass('hide');
  } else {
    var collection = [];
    var widthFree = selectNavbar.width() - selectNavbarHeader.outerWidth(true) - selectNavbar.find('.navbar-right').outerWidth(true);
    $('.adjustable-drop').find('> li').removeClass('hide').each(function() {
      if ( widthFree >= $(this).outerWidth(true) ) {
        widthFree -= $(this).outerWidth(true);
      } else {
        collection.push(this);
      }
    });
    $(collection).addClass('hide');
  }
};

$(window).resize(function() {
  adjustable(); 
});

$(window).trigger('resize');
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">

  <!-- Static navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav adjustable-drop">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Additional-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Additional-2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Additional-3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Additional-4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Additional-5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Additional-6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Additional-7</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Additional-8</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Additional-9</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Additional-10</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="./">Default <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
        <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </nav>

  <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
  
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @django Glad to be useful. Yet I've improved my solution. Please check it. (The first version is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/yt985oxf/1/).)

Comment: I like improved even better.